# Matplotlib for atmosphere profile

Tags: matplotlib

I need to replicate the following image in Python with the input as following for example:

H(km)     P(bar)      T(K)     Den(m-3)   He(VMR)

0.000     2.000e+01   220.000   6.585e+26   1.000e-06

34.647    1.207e+01   153.300   5.703e+26   1.000e-06

```
def al2pres(x):
    return pressure[np.where(altitude == x)[0]]
def pres2al(x):
    return altitude[np.where(pressure == x)[0]]e here
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,10))
color = 'tab:red'

ax1.set_xlabel('Temperature(K)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Altitude(km)')
ax1.plot(temperature, altitude, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax1.set_xlim([50,222])

#twins axes
secax = ax1.secondary_yaxis('right',functions=(al2pres,pres2al))
secax.set_ylabel('Pressure')

plt.show()
```

I tried to use secondary y axis function from matplotlib but unsuccessful. If you have any tips please let me know, much appriciate.

[Replicate this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy2NO.png)

Comment: I just edited it, please let me know if you need any additional information